# .htaccess: hide main folder show only page link

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to learn .htaccess just curious about possibilities like 
I have site like 
`www.mysite.com/pages`. So it is clear I stored html pages into `pages` folder. My HTML pages location will be `www.mysite.com/pages/1.html`. Well it is possible with .htaccess when user want `1.html` it show url like `www.mysite.com/1.html`

Comment: Yes, it is possible with mod_rewrite.

Comment: thanks ...............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using mod_rewrite:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If we are not requesting an existing file/directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  # If the requested URI exists in pages subfolder
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  # Serve content from pages directory.
  RewriteRule ^ pages%{REQUEST_URI}  [L]

</IfModule>
```